# performance between [fixed array] and [pointer with memory allocation]

Tags: c++

I'm making scientific code that calculates very many times(10+ hours), so the speed is far more important than any other thing.

case 1

```
class foo{
public:
  double arr[4] = {0};
  ...

  foo& operator = (foo&& other){
    std::memcpy(arr, other.arr, sizeof(arr));
  }
  ...
}
```

case 2

```
class fee{
public:
  double *arr = nullptr;

  fee(){
    arr = new double[4];
  }
  ~fee(){
    if(arr != nullptr)
      free[] arr;
  }
  ...

  &fee operator = (fee&& other){
    arr = other.arr;
    other.arr = nullptr;
  }
  ...
}
```

These classes are used for vector(length 4) and matrix(size 4x4) calculations.

I heard that arrays of fixed size can be optimized by the compiler.
But in that case, r-value calculations can not be optimized(since all elements have to be copied instead of pointer switching).

```
A = B*C + D;
```

So my question is what is more expensive, memory allocation and freeing or copying close memories?

Or perhaps there is another way to increase the performance(such as making an expression class)?

Comment: Calculation of expressions like `A = B * C + D;` could benefit from [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) technique.

Comment: Memory allocations are done by your OS and time will depend on number of factors such as which OS you are running, type and state of memory (how fragmented it is, how much of it is in use, is there swapping, etc). Copying adjacent regions of memory will give you much more consistent performance figures, based on length. But again, if memory is fragmented in case of virtual memory system what's in your program space adjacent may not be adjacent in physical memory at all.

Answer (score 0):

First performance is not really a language question (except for algorythms used in the standard library) but more an implementation question. Anyway most common implementations use the program stack for automatic variables and a system heap for dynamic ones (allocated through `new`).

In that case the performance will depend on the usage. Heap management has a cost. So if you are frequently allocating and deallocating them, stack management should be the winner. But on the other side moving allocated data is just a matter of pointer exchange when you may need a `memcpy` for non allocated one.

The total memory has also a strong impact. Heap memory is only limited by the free system memory (at run time), while the stack size is normally defined at build time (link phase) and statically allocated at load time. So if the total size is only known at run time, use dynamic memory.

You are here trying to do low level optimization. The rule is then to do *profiling*. Build a small program making the expected usage of those structures, and use a profiling tool(*) with both implementations. I would alse give a try to a standard vector which has nice built-in optimizations.

---

(*) Beware, simply measuring the time of one single run is **not** accurate because it depends of many other parameters such as the load caused by other programs including system ones.